# How can I apply some parts of columns in dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

`data1=pd.DataFrame(data1_added, columns=data1.columns)`

In this code, I want to fill data1_added's first 3 column indexes with column indexes of data1.
(data1 has 3columns and data1_added has 5 columns)

I don't know how to add extra column indexes in this code

Comment: some sample data would be great

Answer (score 0):

If need rename `data1_added.columns` by `data1.columns` create dictionary and pass to `rename`:

```
data1 = data1_added.rename(columns=dict(zip(data1_added.columns, data1.columns)))
```